# How to run mtouch command to launch Xamarin.iOS app on simulator for automated testing?

Tags: testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin and I need to be able to launch a Xamarin iOS app on iOS simulator from command line. I have tried running mtouch but obviously am missing on something as I am not able to successfully launch the app on simulator. I don't know if I am missing on setting any environment variable or am running it from a wrong location as I am getting "Cannot find command" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mtouch -launchsim Hello.app
```

mtouch docs are [here](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=man%3Amtouch%281%29)

On a Mac, the mtouch binary should be here

```
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch
```

Comment: I know the command but when I try to run it on the Mac from the Debug build folder, I get "-bash mtouch - command not found", I don't know how to fix that. I also checked the documentation but there is no mention of the same. I know mtouch.exe exists on my Windows VM under MSBuild/Xamarin/iOS but I don't know how to access that on my Mac.

Comment: In the future, you'll get better answers if you include the relevant info in your Question.  See my edit for the mtouch path

Comment: Cool, that worked! Apologies for not including this info in the question itself.